# Array to String conversion warning in PHP while displaying HTML form data

Tags: php, html

I got an assignment for making a "Daily task manager" in PHP which takes a month, day, year, and task to complete as user input. So for that, I used arrays to display the entered task but it is showing the warning of an array to string. So any idea to fix my mistake?

> Daily Tasks. Display a view of the current day showing each hour of
> the day (from 0:00 to 23:00). The form input should consist of

- A month, day, and year
- 5 tasks to be completed that day. Each task has a description
  (text) and a deadline associated with it (e.g. 10:00, 14:00,
  etc.).

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Daily Task</title>
    <style>
        .a{
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="dailyTask.php" method="POST">
        <label for="month">Month: </label>
        <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="month" class="a"><br>
        <label for="day">Day: </label>
        <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="day" class="a"><br>
        <label for="year">Year: </label>
        <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="year" class="a"><br>
        <label for="00:00">00:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task1[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="01:00">01:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task2[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="02:00">02:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task3[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="03:00">03:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task4[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="04:00">04:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task5[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="05:00">05:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task6[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="06:00">06:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task7[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="07:00">07:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task8[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="08:00">08:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task9[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="09:00">09:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task10[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="10:00">10:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task11[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="11:00">11:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task12[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>    
        <label for="12:00">12:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task13[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="13:00">13:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task14[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="14:00">14:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task15[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="15:00">15:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task16[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="16:00">16:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task17[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="17:00">17:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task18[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="18:00">18:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task19[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="19:00">19:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task20[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="20:00">20:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task21[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="21:00">21:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task22[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="22:00">22:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task23[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br>
        <label for="23:00">23:00</label>
        <input type="text" name="task24[]" placeholder="enter your task"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
    $month = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "month", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $day = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "day", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $year = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "year", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $task1 = $_POST["task1"];
    $task2 = $_POST["task2"];
    $task3 = $_POST["task3"];
    $task4 = $_POST["task4"];
    $task5 = $_POST["task5"];
    $task6 = $_POST["task6"];
    $task7 = $_POST["task7"];
    $task8 = $_POST["task8"];
    $task9 = $_POST["task9"];
    $task10 = $_POST["task10"];
    $task11 = $_POST["task11"];
    $task12 = $_POST["task12"];
    $task13 = $_POST["task13"];
    $task14 = $_POST["task14"];
    $task15 = $_POST["task15"];
    $task16 = $_POST["task16"];
    $task17 = $_POST["task17"];
    $task18 = $_POST["task18"];
    $task19 = $_POST["task19"];
    $task20 = $_POST["task20"];
    $task21 = $_POST["task21"];
    $task22 = $_POST["task22"];
    $task23 = $_POST["task23"];
    $task24 = $_POST["task24"];
    $myArray = Array($task1, $task2, $task3, $task4, $task5, $task6, $task7, $task8, $task9, $task10, $task11, $task12, $task13, $task14, $task15, $task16, $task17, $task18, $task19, $task20, $task21, $task22, $task23, $task24);
    foreach( $myArray as $task ) {
        echo $task . "\n";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Schedule</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Month: <?= $month ?></p>
    <p>Day: <?= $day ?></p>
    <p>Year: <?= $year ?></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here because you name taskx[] your input it create one array, then $taskx is one too, so $myArray is an array of array and finally when you try to echo each in your loop, it's a little different from a string so php point it out.

You can give the same name multiple times with [] it will create a nice array with all values in, and those values will be strings this time.

Comment: I tried by giving the same names but I still cannot figure out the problem can you show me the changes to make??

Comment: We are not really supposed to code everything for you in this site, but here you go (if each task is named task[] you got everything in $_POST['task']) :
foreach ($_POST['task'] as $task) 
{
      echo $task . "<br>";
 }